# Android Studio resizes app icon wrong

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to change the icon of my app in android studio.

I am importing it with Android Studio like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD8vo.png).

(which normally should work)

But on my mobile the App Icon looks like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v8VJ.png).

I don't now what I'm doing wrong so **any** help is appreciated :)

Comment: may be your png height and width is large and cant be set in the middle try to reduce the height and width from photoshop and adobe xd gives the better export icon for android may be there is some issue in the dpi of your mobile size

Comment: Still doesn't work... But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Won't help you a lot if you're staying with that whole png hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi thing but I would suggests you to create an vector art for your app icon. You wouldn't have to care about all these sizes.

Comment: I converted my png to a svg and then to a vector drawable and it does work now. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pngs it's kinda difficult.
You may want to try using vectors:

**First**
Export your logo (using for example photoshop) as a SVG

Then use this Website to convert it to xml code: http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Create a new drawable file and copy the code of the website into your file.

Then try creating your Launcher Icons using your drawable resource file